# create a soap request message

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, soapui

HI while trying to use soapUI, I got error; SOAP RESPONSE FAILED: this is my request xml, I just copy pasted this xml under soapenv:Body, and sumbitted a request, do I need to do something else?

```
<holyrequest xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/webservice Request.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.mywebsite.com/xml/webservice"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<state reached="false">
 <value>Plan</value>
<myvariable>myplan</myvariable>
</state>

 </holyrequest>
```

Comment: you down vote for ego? tell here openly giving your name with the reason so I can learn what's wrong.

Comment: I must say I agree with XD, if you're gonna down-vote something, at least give a reason. How is he or anyone else suppose to learn anything from simply losing a point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it;

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<holyrequest xmlns="http://www.myservice.com/xml/webservice">

<state goalreached="false">
  <value>PlanKB</value>
    <goalvariable>myGoal</goalvariable>
</state>

    </holyrequest>

</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the WSDL of your webservice to your soapUI project:
http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/your-first-soapui-project.html

Then soapUI will generate you demo requests and you can see the required structure of a request.